# concat specific rows of two pandas dataframe using data in two columns as reqs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2, where

both have subframes "data" and "metadata," and DF1 has substantially more rows than DF2

```
DF1 
     DATA            METADATA
     0 1 2 3 4 5     attr1      attr2        ..  attrN
11   1 1 1 1 1 1     000        apple
13   1 1 1 1 1 1     140        orange
19   1 1 1 1 1 1     199        pineapple
25   1 5 1 1 1 2     000        apple
..

DF2 
     DATA        METADATA
     x y z k     attr1      attr2            ..  attrK
000  2 2 2 2     000        bean
001  2 2 2 2     001        bean
002  2 2 2 2     002        bean
003  2 2 2 2     003        bean
..
199  2 2 2 2     199        bean
200  2 2 2 2     000        orange
201  2 2 2 2     001        orange
..
340  1 2 3 4     140        orange
..
500  4 3 2 1     000        apple
..
700  2 2 2 2     350        bread
..
999  5 5 5 5     199        pineapple
```

I want to concatenate columnwise specific rows in DF2 to rows in DF1, based off attributes in DF2.

Specifically:

For every row in DF1, I want to concatenate just the DATA from the row in DF2 such that the entry in DF1.METADATA.attr1 & DF2.METADATA.attr1 and DF1.METADATA.attr2 & DF2.METADATA.attr2 are the same, for each row. The result here would be:

```
 DF3 (desired result)
       DATA                  METADATA
       0 1 2 3 4 5 x y z k   attr1       attr2       .. attr N
 11    1 1 1 1 1 1 4 3 2 1   000         apple
 13    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4   140         orange
 19    1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5   199         pineapple
 25    1 5 1 1 1 2 4 3 2 1   000         apple
```

I have managed to do it by looping through, but I get a terrible runtime and having a lot of data I need to make it run faster and there should be a quick and easy way to do this through pandas (i think!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a merge on attr1, something like:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

For example (slightly tweaked):

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]:
   DATA                METADATA
      0  1  2  3  4  5    attr1      attr2
11    1  1  1  1  1  1        0       bean
13    1  1  1  1  1  1      140     orange
19    1  1  1  1  1  1      199  pineapple
25    1  5  1  1  1  2        0      apple

In [12]: df2
Out[12]:
  DATA          METADATA
     x  y  z  k    attr1  attr2
0    2  2  2  2        0   bean
1    7  2  2  2        0  apple
2    2  2  2  2        2   bean
3    7  2  2  2        3   bean

In [13]: df1.merge(df2, how="left")
Out[13]:
  DATA                METADATA            DATA
     0  1  2  3  4  5    attr1      attr2    x    y    z    k
0    1  1  1  1  1  1        0       bean  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
1    1  1  1  1  1  1      140     orange  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    1  1  1  1  1  1      199  pineapple  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    1  5  1  1  1  2        0      apple  7.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Note: this merges on the shared columns, in this case METADATA attr1 and attr2. See the [merge section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: i think this MAY work; let me test it. Ideally i want to have the two DATAs in the final dataframe to be under one DATA, but thats an easy fix I can do myself. 

However, does this generalize to when I have multiple attributes that I don't want to merge based on whatsoever? For example, if in your example, i have several more attributes in both df1 and df2, and all of these attributes are totally irrelevant to what I want to merge on